# Given a function $\phi:X \to Y$ and a target distribution $\pi_Y$ on $Y$, does there exist a distribution $\pi_X$ on $X$ s.t. $\phi(x) \sim \pi_Y$?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, random-variable, jacobian, determinant

More formally, given $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, $Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$, $\phi: X \to Y$ and distribution $\pi_Y$ on $Y$, does there exist a distribution $\pi_X$ on $X$ such that $\phi(x) \sim \pi_Y$ when $x \sim \pi_X$?

In some cases, we have proof by construction. When $m=n$ and $\phi$ is sufficently well-behaved, the density of the desired distribution is $$\pi_X = \pi_Y(\phi(x))|\det J_\phi(x)|$$ where $J_\phi(x)$ is the jacobian of $\phi$ w.r.t. $x$. Similarly, when $m<n$ and $\phi$ is a bijection, we can write $$\pi_X = \frac{\pi_Y(\phi(x))}{\textrm{vol}\; J_{\phi^{-1}}(\phi(x))}$$

Does this also hold when $m < n$ but $\phi$ is not a bijection, and in particular when $\phi$ is scalar? I'm not necessarily interested in finding the distribution so much as proving/disproving its existence for any/all $\phi$, $\pi_Y$ pair(s) in the context of Bayesian inference: is it sufficiently expressive to use a fixed prior function $\phi$ because there exists a posterior $\pi_X$ such that $\phi(x)$ matches the true $\pi_Y$?

Comment: If one defines the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B_X=\phi^{-1}(\mathcal B_Y)$ and the distribution $\pi_X$ by$$\pi_X(A)=\mathbb P(X\in A)=\mathbb P(\phi(X)\in\phi(A))=\pi_Y(\phi(A))\qquad A\in\mathcal B_X$$the push-forward measure $\phi_*(\pi_X)$ is equal to $\pi_Y$.

Comment: Some useful search terms with respect to this problem are "measure transport" and "optimal transport".